# Windows server 2019 alias doesn't work in some scenarios

Tags: windows, networking, unc

I'm migrating to a new server and have created alias's to our common resources such as our file share. My server name is S1-FS but I setup it up so it can be accessed with UNC path `//fileshare`. In the future I want to be be able to migrate these resources and only have to update the DNS record instead of all the GPO's and breaking everyone's personal device mappings.

I used the following command to setup the alias:

```
Netdom computername S1-FS /add:fileshare
```

This works for most things but I've found this does not work with a few old printers and QuickBooks:

- Our newer printers all connect just fine but older ones timeout. Primary DNS is set to our local Windows DNS server. This is for setting up a scan to drop the file on our share.
- Quickbooks work with the alias UNC on a domain joined computer but our accountants personal device says its not reachable when opening QuickBooks from the share. I'm able to map the share on his personal device with the alias.

Is there something other than CNAME and SPN that need to be setup to support older devices?

Answer (score 0):

it may be this - I have had a similar issue
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-cname-alias-cannot-access-smb-file-server-share

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/540297)